# changing textview from another class crashes everything

Tags: android, textview, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a alarm receiver that runs in mainActivity everyday at a specific time everyday:

```
    public void scheduleAlarm() 
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

in the other class called alarmReceiver I try to change a textView context but it crashes...

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TextView black;

    black = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.BlackCounterDisplay);
    black.setText("toto");
}
```

}

can't find why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [look at your stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), you should see a `ClassCastException`, as the `Context` passed to `onReceive()` is not an `Activity`.

Comment: Indeed I see the ClassCastException, so do you have any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @lguenier: It is unclear why you think that you will have an activity at 16:25 each day, let alone think that updating that activity is the proper response to this `AlarmManager` event. Hence, I cannot give you much in the way of specific advice.

Comment: But I think it would be wiser to change the value of the shared preference and then update it on the activity rather than directly changing the display, thanks for making me deduct that.

Answer (score 0):

you make global variable which you should check inside the main activity
and set it to true inside onReceive()
then on the main activity you change the text
but becarefull if you want a single alarm or period alarm